# Connect to Hyperion Essbase using REST Api

Tags: hyperion, essbase

How can we connect to ESSBASE using REST? How can we retrieve data from cubes?

Answer (score 1):

At present, there is no typical REST API for Essbase. There was a SOAP-based Essbase Web Services component that still may technically exist, but it is very difficult to use. To achieve a REST API for Essbase, you would have to design a custom middle-tier component (a Java servlet) that would use the Essbase Java API to provide yourself a REST API.